# How to get the root path of my project?

Tags: java, jsp

I have JSP projects that run in Tomcat developed in Eclipse.

I want to have some files which I store inside the project.

Here is the project structure that I have:

```
.settings
build
data
ImportedClasses
src
WebContent
.classpath
.project
```

I want to access the `data` folder from my code in JSP file which located in `WebContent`.

Tried some code below:

```
File userDataDirFile = new File ( "data" );
String path = userDataDirFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

prints

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\data\users
```

---

Then

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()
```

prints

```
C:/Workspaces/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/survey/WEB-INF/classes/
```

---

Another one:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

prints

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse
```

---

There is no code that I tried (I think the 2nd solution supposed to work, but it doesn't) can locate me to root folder of my project. Anyone can advise?

Comment: Why do you want to access the data folder? What about situations when the application might be packaged in a war and deployed to some server? In those situations the data folder might be in a different place or inside your war, so maybe it would be best to just declare it in some configuration/properties store (file, database etc.).

Comment: file that are not in WebContent will not be deployed with your war check my updated answer.

Comment: Does the data folder will change place when I package it to war file and deploy to cloud? The data folder consists of some files, such as, localization file, users file, format file, and some other files. Since this project is an open-source project, and must be up soon, I don't want to change lot of code there. Therefore, I thought the best way is to get the root project and refer to `data` folder (the original code requires the `data` folder in root of C folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :** File that are not in WebContent will not be deployed  with your war. you have to put files used in you code inside the WebContent and try with [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) which point to the root folder of the your web application :
if your file is at the same folder as WEB-INF then :

```
ServletContext context = getContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/data");
```

by the way if you don't want to give direct access to `data` file it's recommanded to put it in WEB-INF so that no one can have access to them directly.

Comment: Ok I understand. Btw, how to have `getContext()` ? It gives me undefined error. Is it `getServletContext()` ?

Comment: I tried with `getServletContext()` and it returns me `C:\Workspaces\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\survey\data` :(

Comment: from your servlet yes , it's `getServletContext()`

Comment: Oh it is supposed not to be in JSP file? Sorry I am not really expert in JSP.

Comment: yes it's normal that's the expected result because starting Tomcat app from Eclipse  will always deploy in a folder like this one (tmp0 could change to tmp1 tmp2..) .the file here is a copy of the original one.

Comment: I see.. So it should be fine then? I will try to deploy it to cloud and will update you by next week. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
String caminhoProjeto = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
```

This is like "src" path, but is the "classes" path of binaries files context after deployment and runtime.

My class for example of the necessarie use of this way "root dir of project":

---

PropertiesReader.java:

```
public class PropertiesReader {

    public static String projectPath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
    public static String propertiesPath = "/META-INF/";

    public static Properties loadProperties(String propertiesFileName) throws IOException {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(new FileInputStream(projectPath + propertiesPath + propertiesFileName));
        return p;
    }

    public static String getText(String propertiesFileName, String propertie) {

        try {
            return loadProperties(propertiesFileName).getProperty(propertie);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return propertie;
    }
}
```

PersonRegistration.java:

```
@ManagedBean
public class PersonRegistration {
    private Integer majority = Integer.parseInt(PropertiesLeitor.getText("Brasil.properties", "pessoa.maioridade"));
}
```

Brasil.properties (within src / META-INF):

```
pessoa.maioridade = 18
```